# PHP-FPM failed to connect to FastCGI server

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

So i was setting up PHP5-FPM for the first time, at first everything went well i can see my site up and running until i did a bit of a tweak in

```
/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

Specifically on these lines:

```
pm.max_children = 100 # The hard-limit total number of processes allowed
pm.start_servers = 20 # When nginx starts, have this many processes waiting for requests
pm.min_spare_servers = 10 # Number spare processes nginx will create
pm.max_spare_servers = 20 # Number spare processes attempted to create
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s;
```

When i restart apache and php5-fpm service, i get the following error:

```
[Wed Nov 25 02:39:43.973654 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 5438] (2)No such file or directory: [client 36.72.129.207:60098] FastCGI: failed to connect to server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi": connect() failed
[Wed Nov 25 02:39:43.973705 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 5438] [client 36.72.129.207:60098] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi"
```

So i thought that this is because i am not connected using UNIX socket, so i checked in my www.conf file again:

and i can verify it that :

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
```

And my php5-fpm.conf is as follow:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization

<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

</IfModule>
```

And my apache2.conf is as follows:

```
<IfModule fastcgi_module>
  # Add a new action that points to a virtual (non-existent) handler.
  # I will repeat, NON-EXISTENT. This is a virtual (non-existent) handler.
  #   i.e. `/fastcgi.php5-fpm` does not exist, that's OK :-)
  # The name of our handler is decided here. Let's call it `fastcgi-php5-fpm`.
  # See also <http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_actions.html#action>

  Action fastcgi-php5-fpm /fastcgi.php5-fpm virtual

  # Now let's add an alias mapping that gives meaning to our virtual handler.
  # This forwards requests hitting our virtual (non-existent) handler;
  # sending them to FastCGI; which is yet another virtual handler.
  # I repeat, NON-EXISTENT. This is a virtual handler that does not exist.
  #   i.e. `/var/www/cgi-bin/fastcgi.php5-fpm` does not exist, that's OK :-)
  # See also <http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias>

  Alias /fastcgi.php5-fpm /var/www/cgi-bin/fastcgi.php5-fpm

  # Now, let's setup FastCGI so it works w/ our virtual handler and PHP5-FPM.
  # See also <http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html#FastCgiExternalServer>

  FastCgiExternalServer /var/www/cgi-bin/fastcgi.php5-fpm -socket /var/run/php5-fpm.sock -idle-timeout 900 -pass-header Authorization -pass-he$

  # Associate our handler with PHP files; including PHAR files.

  AddHandler fastcgi-php5-fpm php phar
</IfModule>
```

What i still dont understand why is suddenly my Apache giving me 500 error saying that it can't connect while 5 minutes ago, it did...

Can anyone please help me with this...